# Can I force code review before check-ins in the TFS plug-in for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tfs, sonarqube

Is there any way in the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse to ensure that a user has performed a code review using Sonar before check-in?  We want to enforce Code review before any checkin in TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Version Control supports [check-in policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx) that can evaluate whether your pending changes meet the validation requirements before they can be checked in to the server.  However there is no out of the box check-in policy for Sonar.

Team Explorer Everywhere does have an [SDK for developing custom check-in policies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22616) in Java, that will be evaluated by Team Explorer Everywhere.  If Sonar's code review can be called programmatically, then you can build a custom check-in policy that calls Sonar inside the `Evaluate` method.

Note that the check-in policy is executed frequently, so if code review is long-running, you probably want to simply set a flag on the project that code review has been run recently, and check for that flag in your `Evaluate` method, instead of re-running code review each time the check-in policy is called.

Building a custom check-in policy in Java for TEE is surprisingly easy - there is sample code in the SDK archive that you can leverage.

Comment: Thanks Edward for your inputs! I'll quickly verify the way you suggested, and will revert in case of any further doubts.